# handlebarsjs like Templating in web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to use handlebarsjs like templating in c# web form application. This is a rough look of template that i need to render. currently i am doing this using find and replace text. But its making my code too messy especially on if else parts.
Are there any templating libraries that can help me render this..!!

```
<ul>
  {{#each items}}
  <li>
     <h1>{{post_title}}</h1>
     <p>{{post_description}}</p>
     <small>{{post_date}}</small>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Another example :

```
<ul>
  {{#each items}}
  <li>
     <h1>{{post_title}}</h1>
     <p>
       {{#if short-desc}}
          {{post_description}}
       {{#else}}
          {{post_long_description}}
       {{#end if}}
     </p>
     {{#if display-date}}
       <small>{{post_date}}</small>
     {{#end if}}
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you can't use HandlebarsJS? It's certainly possible to use it in a webforms application.  You can use something like JQuery's Ajax functionality to get the data to be rendered. I'm using exactly this in an application and it works beautifully (though beware of bugs in Safari if you have users on iOS).